# What is fast and safe way to revert code from git repo

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, git, github

By mistake I have pushed changes to git repo..now I want to revert it back.

So what is fast and safe way to do that.

I know about to reverse it but I would like to know about easy, fast and safe way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use for keep your changes in stage area

> Mixed Reset

```
git reset --mixed [commit id you want to reset here]
```